# md-autocomplete generating the same model in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, md-autocomplete

md-autocomplete generating the same model in ng-repeat
if the value of one changes reflect in other fields as well,
How can I add different ng model to it?

```
<tr ng-repeat="school in ctrl.schools" ng-if="ctrl.editAcademyToggle">
<td>
<md-input-container>
<div class="mdInputContainer">
    <md-autocomplete flex required flex-gt-sm="25"
        md-autofocus="true"
        md-selected-item="school.college_name"
        md-clear-button="false"
        md-input-name="school.college"
        md-input-minlength="3"
        md-no-cache="false"
        md-search-text="ctrl.academySearchStr"
        md-items="item in ctrl.searchAcademySchools(ctrl.academySearchStr)"     
        md-item-text="item.name">
        <md-item-template>
            <span class="item-title">
                <span> {{item.name}}, {{item.city}}, {{item.state}}, {{item.zip}}</span>
            </span>
        </md-item-template>
        <md-not-found>
            <span ng-if="ctrl.academySearchStr.length < 3">Minimum 3 Charaters</span>
            <span ng-if="ctrl.academySearchStr.length >= 3">
              Wait a few more seconds before searching again"
            </span>
        </md-not-found>
        <div ng-messages="ctrl.leadEntryForm.school.college.$error">
            <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
        </div>
    </md-autocomplete>
</div>
</md-input-container>
</td>
</tr>
```

The Generated Model Coming something like this for all Rows :

```
ng-model="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.scope.searchText"
```

Comment: this `ctrl.academySearchStr` looks same for all repeated items inside `md-search-text`. is it ?

Comment: Does that really matter, anyway we can see the ouput in the variable you have binded in `md-selected-item="school.college_name"` so in the javascript, we can see that the selected value will be present in `$scope.school.college_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your `schools` as array.

you can map over it add a variable for search text instead of using same search text everywhere, like this

```
schools.map(function(obj){
    obj.searchText = null;
});
```

And pass this search text here

```
md-search-text="school.searchText"
```